# Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated unable to load program

Tags: prolog, dcg, instantiation-error

When trying to load my file Tutorial_2 which is using DCG to count how many zero's are in a sentence or 1s and 0s ending with a 2.

When I try and load the process I get a arguments are not sufficiently instantiated for the prolog SWI init file:

```
[debug]  ?- [Tutorial_2].
ERROR: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated
ERROR: In:
ERROR:   [15] throw(error(instantiation_error,_12554))
ERROR:   [14] '$instantiation_error'(_12578) at c:/program files/swipl/boot/init.pl:3608
ERROR:   [13] '$load_files'(_12602,user,[expand(true)]) at c:/program files/swipl/boot/init.pl:1946
ERROR:   [12] load_files(user:_12648,[expand(true)]) at c:/program files/swipl/boot/init.pl:1941
ERROR:   [11] consult(user:_12688) at c:/program files/swipl/boot/init.pl:1930
ERROR:   [10] [user:_12720] at c:/program files/swipl/boot/init.pl:1918
ERROR:    [9] <user>
```

The file is there and has not been edited since I installed prolog 3 months ago.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Tutorial_2` is a variable (hence the instantiation error) but the Prolog top-level shortcut for consulting a file takes a ground term. As `Tutorial_2` starts with an uppercase letter, to make it an atom, write it between single quotes:

```
?- ['Tutorial_2'].
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the pl file name needs to be small-lettered all the way.

For your case rename your pl file to

> tutorial2.pl

Comment: `?- ['Test 1'].` works fine to load file 'Test 1.pl' - which Prolog system and version are you using?